# Split string into lines and sentences, but ignoring abbrevations

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

There is some string content, which I have to split. First of all I need to split the string content into lines.

This is how I do that:

```
str.split('\n').forEach((item) => {
    if (item) {
        // TODO: split also each line into sentences

        let     data       = {
                    type   : 'item',
                    content: [{
                        content  : item,
                        timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
                    }]
                };

        // Save `data` to DB
    }
});
```

But now I need to split also each line into sentences. The difficulty to me for this is to split it correctly. Therefore I would use `.` (dot and space) to split the line. 
BUT there is also an array of abbrevations, which should NOT split the line:

```
cont abbr = ['vs.', 'min.', 'max.']; // Just an example; there are 70 abbrevations in that array
```

... and there are a few more rules:

1. Any number and dot or single letter and dot should also be ignored as split string: `1.`, `2.`, `30.`, `A.`, `b.`
2. Upper and lower case should be ignored: `Max. Lorem ipsum` should not be splitted. `Lorem max. ipsum` either.

**Example**

```
const str = 'Just some examples:\nThis example has min. 2 lines. Max. 10 lines. There are some words: 1. Foo and 2. bar.';
```

The result of that should be four data-objects:

```
{ type: 'item', content: [{ content: 'Just some examples:', timestamp: 123 }] }
{ type: 'item', content: [{ content: 'This example has min. 2 lines.', timestamp: 123 }] }
{ type: 'item', content: [{ content: 'Max. 10 lines.', timestamp: 123 }] }
{ type: 'item', content: [{ content: 'There are some words: 1. Foo and 2. bar.', timestamp: 123 }] }
```

Comment: You might, possibly, be able to do this with one regex (I couldn't but that doesn't mean it's not possible), but it'll be a beast to write and maintain. I'd suggest using a very permissive regex to scan the string for potential matches and then evaluating them in context against a set of rules like you describe. It's still going to be complex, but it should at least be easier to read and troubleshoot. Also, if you're splitting natural language text, don't overlook patterns like `"Hello. I'm Sue," she said. "Is this a string?" she asked. "It is."` and formations like `I like the word "string".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first detect the abbreviations and the numberings in the string, and replace the dot by a dummy string in each one. After splitting the string on the remaining dots, which signal the end of a sentence, you can restore the original dots. Once you have the sentences, you can split each one on newline characters like you do in your original code.

The updated code allows for more than one dot in the abbreviations (as shown for `p.o.` and `s.v.p.`).

```js
var i, j, strRegex, regex, abbrParts;
const DOT = "_DOT_";
const abbr = ["p.o.", "s.v.p.", "vs.", "min.", "max."];

var str = 'Just some examples:\nThis example s.v.p. has min. 2 lines. Max. 10 lines. There are some words: 1. Foo and 2. bar. And also A. p.o. professional letters.';

console.log("String: " + str);

// Replace dot in abbreviations found in string
for (i = 0; i < abbr.length; i++) {
    abbrParts = abbr[i].split(".");
    strRegex = "(\\W*" + abbrParts[0] + ")";
    for (j = 1; j < abbrParts.length - 1; j++) {
        strRegex += "(\\.)(" + abbrParts[j] + ")";
    }
    strRegex += "(\\.)(" + abbrParts[abbrParts.length - 1] + "\\W*)";
    regex = new RegExp(strRegex, "gi");
    str = str.replace(regex, function () {
        var groups = arguments;
        var result = groups[1];
        for (j = 2; j < groups.length; j += 2) {
            result += (groups[j] === "." ? DOT + groups[j+1] : "");
        }
        return result;
    });
}

// Replace dot in numbers found in string
str = str.replace(/(\W*\d+)(\.)/gi, "$1" + DOT);

// Replace dot in letter numbering found in string
str = str.replace(/(\W+[a-zA-Z])(\.)/gi, "$1" + DOT);

// Split the string at dots
var parts = str.split(".");

// Restore dots in sentences
var sentences = [];
regex = new RegExp(DOT, "gi");
for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i].trim().length > 0) {
        sentences.push(parts[i].replace(regex, ".").trim() + ".");
        console.log("Sentence " + (i + 1) + ": " + sentences[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have forgotten a type of abbrevation: These can have two dots, like `p.o.`. This would create for the string `professional` with your code a new string `p_DOT_ofessional` - which shouldn't. How do I have to improve your code?

Comment: `new RegExp("(\W*" + abbrParts[0] + ")(\.)(" + abbrParts[1] + "\W*)", "gi")` contains a common mistake with backslashes. `"\."` is an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks for pointing that out. I will double the backslash for escape characters. I forgot to do it when switching from the `/.../` form (in my initial tests) to `new RegExp("...")`.

Comment: @user3142695 - I updated my answer to allow for multiple dots in abbreviations. The new code snippet shows examples for `p.o.` and `s.v.p.`. The backslash problem signaled by @WiktorStribizew was also fixed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Great. Thanks for that. Cannot give you more credit :-)

Comment: You could but I will not ask for it. :-)